# Why Glyphicons not show into text box in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in bootstrap and want to use Glyphicons in text box,for that purpose write this code:

```
<div class="inner-addon left-addon">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

but show me this:
[image]

How can i show Glyphicons  into text box not out of that?thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just check this code..

```
<div class="inner-addon left-addon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div
```

css

```
/* enable absolute positioning */
.inner-addon { 
    position: relative; 
}

/* style icon */
.inner-addon .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* align icon */
.left-addon .glyphicon  { left:  0px;}
.right-addon .glyphicon { right: 0px;}

/* add padding  */
.left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }
.right-addon input { padding-right: 30px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really, but you can kind of fake it like this:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #DDD;">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" ></i>
    <input style="border: none;"/>
</div>
```

The short answer is, because you can't place the actual icon inside the "value" attribute inside input, you are not able to put the glyphicon in there. But this way visually it would look similar to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `glyphicon` `position: absolute;` and parent `div` `relative`:

```css
.inner-addon {
  position: relative;
  /* margin just for breathe from viewport */
  margin-top: 20px;
}

input {
  /* give text some indent so it doesn't collapse with icon */
  text-indent: 18px;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-user {
  position: absolute;
  /* Adjust coordinates as desired */
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="inner-addon left-addon">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
```